# Any alternative way of using this .charAt()?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, when I used `input[index]` in the statement the reverse word didn't match the value of inputString. But this works in C#. When I try it in JavaScript is not working. I want to learn what are the other alternative way of `.char()` method. Can anybody solve my problem?

```
strReverse = "";
input = document.getElementById("inputValue").value;
i = input.length;

for(var j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
     strReverse = strReverse + input.charAt(j); // i used input[index]  
}
```

Comment: But your code works as it is. Can you provide a test input where it doesnt

Comment: `strReverse = input.split('').reverse().join('')` FTW

Comment: I doubt this works in C#. It uses the same indexing method as most languages, so there's nothing at `input[j]` when `j = input.length`

Comment: This question isn't complete. What's the result when you run the two code snippets. This should be easy to debug, you should dump `input.charAt(j)` and `input[index]`, and see if they are different.

Comment: @JaromandaX  `input.split('').reverse().join('') ` DOES NOT WORK for a lot of unicode characters.   Please quit recommending this.  Use `Array.from()` instead.  Try this in your console: `"".split("").join(" ")`

Comment: Whatever. No need to shout Jerome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use `input[index]` instead of `input.charAt()` then you need to address the issue that you are setting `i = input.length;`

So when you enter your loop for the first iteration, `j` will be equal to `i`. Meaning that you are trying to access the character at the index equal to the length of the string (when you do `input[j]`). However, as arrays and string indexing starts at zero in javascript (and in most languages), there is no index at `i` (the length of the string), but, there is an index at `i-1`, which will give the last character in the string. Thus, if you want to reverse your array using `input[j]` you need to start `j` in your for loop as `j = i - 1`.

Take a look at the snippet for a working example:

```js
strReverse = "";
input = "level";
i = input.length;

for(var j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
     strReverse = strReverse + input[j]; // i used input[index]  
}

if(strReverse === input) {
  alert(input +" is a palindrome!")
} else {
  alert(input +" is not a palindrome!");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I put index instead of j. My real problem is when I used input[j] it didn't match to input value. I used this code.

Comment: Okay, but it should work now. Take a look at the code snippet again

Comment: @LizQuenUpdate great! Make sure to mark your question answered :)

Comment: Got it! Now I know my real problem :)

Comment: Accessing strings like arrays does not work with high-order unicode characters.  Just use `Array.from` to turn the string into an array.